# Alpine.js - nested components

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have code like this with nested components:

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div x-data="{isOpen: false}">
    <div x-data="{isOtherOpen: false}">
     
     
     <a href="#" @click="isOpen = !isOpen">Toogle element</a>

      <div x-show="isOpen">
        Now element is opened

      </div>


      <a href="#" @click="isOtherOpen = !isOtherOpen">Toogle other element</a>

      <div x-show="isOtherOpen">
        Now other element is opened
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

but it seems it does not work. Is there any why to make it work using nested components or maybe Alpine.js cannot handle this yet? OF course I'm aware that changing:

```
<div x-data="{isOpen: false}">
   <div x-data="{isOtherOpen: false}">
```

into

```
<div x-data="{isOpen: false, isOtherOpen: false}">
   <div>
```

would solve the issue, but this way I would have single component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alpine.js doesn't support nesting as of v2.x latest.

If you don't want to combine everything into a single component, you can have 2 components side by side and you can setup communication between them with `$dispatch` to send custom events and `x-on:custom-event.window` to listen to the event.

Comment: HI, Hugo how to correct this I'm new to alpine please help.
```
    <div x-data="{ atTop: true ,isOpen: false}">
 <nav
 class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap p-6 fixed w-full z-10 top-0"
 
 @keydown.escape="isOpen = false"
 :class="{ 'shadow-lg bg-white' : isOpen , 'bg-gray-800 bg-opacity-25' : !isOpen}"
 :class="{ 'bg-white shadow-md' : !atTop }"
 @scroll.window="atTop = (window.pageYOffset > 40) ? false : true"
    >
    ```

Comment: for nav, i have 2 things one for mobile dropdown and the other is when scrolling change background

Answer (score 4):

Currently, in Alpine v2, if you nested a component inside another component, you would not be able to access the parent component easily. Now, in version 3 it's going to be a piece of cake :

```
<div x-data="{ firstName: 'John' }">
    <div x-data="{ lastName: 'Doe' }">
        <span x-text="firstName + ' ' + lastName"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nested components are going to make communicating between components super duper easy . Expect to see this awesomeness available in the next version.

Answer (score 2):

nesting of alpine components is simple in 3.

But what you should really learn about in v3 is that they now have global state handling via https://alpinejs.dev/magics/store

https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store

those are the main takeaways